# InnoDB и Полнотекстовый поиск

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

Так как *innoDB* не включает в себя полнотекстовый поиск, я решил добавить зеркальную таблицу на движке *MyISAM* с индексом `FULLTEXT`, в дополнение к основной таблице. Пример:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_search` (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_post INT( 33 ),
text_post MEDIUMTEXT,
FULLTEXT (`text_post`),
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_main` (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_user INT( 33 ),
id_post INT( 33 ),
text_post MEDIUMTEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Для вывода пользовательских данных на страницу использую таблицу `tab_main`. Для поиска использую `tab_search`. Данные в обе таблицы заносятся одновременно. Поисковый запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```sql
SELECT tab_main.id_user, MATCH (tab_search.text_post) AGAINST ('$my_text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relev 
FROM tab_main, tab_search 
WHERE tab_main.id_post=tab_search.id_post 
AND MATCH (tab_search.text_post) AGAINST ('$my_text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY relev DESC
```

Как видно из этих примеров, поле `text_post` содержится в обоих таблицах. А это значит, что одни и те же данные приходится хранить на обоих таблицах. Это также означает, что придётся выделять в два раза больше памяти для хранения этих данных. Вопрос. Возможно ли полностью убрать поле `text_post` из таблицы `tab_search`, но убрать его так, чтобы в таблицу всё таки записывались данные по индексам. Проще говоря создать отдельную таблицу исключительно с индексами, а всё лишнее убрать.

Comment: А не проще использовать специальные системы поиска для этого? например, [sphinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: @ВОРОН, нет желания пользоваться сторонними библиотеками. Стараемся довольствоваться тем, что имеем. Собственно данный пример работает прекрасно. За исключением того, что хотелось бы убрать `text_post` из таблицы `tab_search` в целях экономии дискового пространства.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с версии MySQL 5.6.4, в InnoDB доступен [полнотекстовый поиск](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

Пример запроса для создания таблицы `full_text_table` с полнотекстовым индексом `idx` по полю `opening_line`:

```
CREATE TABLE full_text_table (
    id           INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    opening_line TEXT(500),
    author       VARCHAR(200),
    title        VARCHAR(200),
    FULLTEXT idx (opening_line)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.